# php register form showing white page

Tags: php, html, database, forms, pdo

I am writing a registration form using pdo ext in php but it seems i have some sort of compiling error since i cannot view the page anymore. It just comes up white.

In the end i would like it to input the 4 fields into the database ready to be used with the login system that is already fully functional.

Here is the php & html

```
<form method="post">
<div class="form-box">
    <span class="fullname"><p>Full Name: </p></span>
    <input class="fullname-box" type='text' name='fullname'/>
</div>
<div class="form-box">
    <span class="email"><p>Email: </p></span>
    <input class="email-box" type='text' name='email'/>
</div>
<div class="form-box">
    <span class="password"><p>Password: </p></span>
    <input class="password-box" type='password' name='password'/>
</div>
<div class="form-box">
    <span class="company"><p>Company (optional): </p></span>
    <input class="company-box" type='text' name='company'/>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <button class="button" type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />Register </button>
    <?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        if ($statement->execute()) {

        function getPdo()
            {
                $dsn = sprintf(
                    'mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=utf8',
                    'bifmcpd.db.13611704.hostedresource.com',
                    'bifmcpd');

                    return new PDO($dsn, '********', '********');
            }
                     $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
                     $email = $_POST['email'];
                    $password = $_POST['password'];
                    $company = $_POST['company']; 

                    $pdo = getpdo();
                    $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO icelivestream VALUES (':fullname', ':email', ':password', ':company');")
                    $statement->bindParam(':fullname', $fullname);
                    $statement->bindParam(':email', $email);
                    $statement->bindParam(':password', $password);
                    $statement->bindParam(':company', $company);

                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://cpdonline.tv/ice-events/livestream.php" </script>';

                    $pdo = null;
        }    
    }

    ?>
</div>
</form>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Edit: now the page is live and the form works... sort of. Information is being entered into the DB but its not the actual inputted information.. :fullname :email :password :company are the only things entering the database on submit

Comment: You need to turn on error reporting and/or logging

Comment: Would you mind letting me know how to do that?

Comment: Look in the PHP documentation for configuration.  Also, your script isn't actually going to save anything to the database.  And I hope that's not your real database username and password in there!

Comment: the host is different :) i think? lol... im new to this php stuff

Comment: At the top of your file add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` to turn on error reporting.

Comment: You need to validate the user submitted data to make sure that the data is valid and the passwords should never be stored in plain text form. Passwords should be stored in hashed form

Comment: @Peter, That makes no difference 

SpacePhoenix has been noted. Thanks!

Comment: There are two pages on the PHP.net website that would have helped you debug and fix your code. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$statement variable is undefined.

You need to put:

```
if ($statement->execute()) {
```

After `$statement->bindParam(':company', $company);` so it will look like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    function getPdo()
        {
            $dsn = sprintf(
                'mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=utf8',
                'bifmcpd.db.13611704.hostedresource.com',
                'bifmcpd');

                return new PDO($dsn, '***', '***');
        }
        $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $company = $_POST['company']; 

        $pdo = getpdo();
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO icelivestream VALUES (:fullname, :email, :password, :company);");
        $statement->bindParam(':fullname', $fullname);
        $statement->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $statement->bindParam(':password', $password);
        $statement->bindParam(':company', $company);

        if ($statement->execute()) {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://cpdonline.tv/ice-events/livestream.php" </script>';
        }
        $pdo = null;   
}
```

Alternatively add: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` just before: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')  {`.

### EDIT:

You don't need single quotes around params in prepare, just use: `$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO icelivestream VALUES (:fullname, :email, :password, :company);");`

Comment: Nothing changes, i sitll get a white page

Comment: You are missing a semicolon on the end of the $pdo->prepare(); I have updated my answer code too.

Comment: If it's sorted then, can you mark my comment as a correct answer, please? Thanks.

Comment: not quite sorted. check my edit. Information is being put into the database but its not the entered information

Comment: Thats fixed it. Thanks!